# json response to Dart loop

Tags: json, flutter

I am trying to show my data to dart widget. The data is coming as json format

```
response = {ID_1: {name: GT06N-17924, v: true, f: false, st: off}, ID_2: {name: GT06N-25723, v: true, f: false, st: false}}
```

and I am trying to show in widget like this:

```
for(var i in response)
       new Text(i['name']);
```

but it is showing me error "type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'"

Any idea to solve this issue will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use `response.values` in iteration.

Comment: hi.. thanks for your reply and its working... one more thing. can we push the key ID_1 into the values object during the loop of the values? i.e: for(i in response.values)  i['imei'] = ID_1

Comment: Yes, You can update them like `for(var i in response.keys) response[i]['imei'] = i;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use **response.values** in iteration look like below,

```
for(var i in response.values)
       new Text(i['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

First You should convert json into dart object. Create a dart file using [online json to dart convertor](https://www.dripcoding.com/json-to-dart/) (suppose file name is model_myresponse ). Check below code to access the item inside JSON response.

```
final Map<String, dynamic> parsed = await wrapper.get_CategoryFull(catid);
final model = get_model_category.fromJson(parsed);
if (model.information.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < model.information.length; i++) {
        catlist.add(new model_categoryitem(model.information[i].id, model.information[i].name,
            model.information[i].imgUrl));
      }

    }
```

You must convert the JSON into dart object then only you can access the json object easily.